# Action Bar Tabs at the bottom?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to place the action bar tabs at the bottom of my app, but I need some help with it (if it's even possible).

The code:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab().setText("Games");
        ActionBar.Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab().setText("Apps");
        ActionBar.Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab().setText("Themes");

        tabA.setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener());
        tabB.setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener());
        tabC.setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener());

        actionBar.addTab(tabA);
        actionBar.addTab(tabB);
        actionBar.addTab(tabC);
```

Comment: @powder366 this can be accomplished pretty easily using a ViewPager and TabPagerIndicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of goes against the Android guidelines to put tabs on the bottom, but a [split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried that already, but the tabs are still at the top... the only thing that moved to the bottom is the MenuItem.

Comment: You might just have to implement custom tabs or use a ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator, I'm not sure if the stock Action Bar is capable of having bottom tabs

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to this but you have to use FrgamentTabHost.

Here is the code.
layout/activity_main.xml

```
enter <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >      

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
      <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You have to place TabWidget below the FrameLayout.

layout/fragment_layout.xml

```
enter code here<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#eaecee">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

MainActivity.java

```css
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1", null),
                FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2", null),
                FragmentTab.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", null),
                FragmentTab.class, null);
    }
}
```

FragmentTab.java

```css
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(this.getTag() + " Content");
        return v;
    }
}
```

I hope it would help you.