# Android actionbar bottom - Fragment Naviagtion

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

I made a fragment tabnaivgation with an actionbar.
The navigation works fine, but I need them at the bottom of the screen.

*I know that it doesnt´t confirm to the Android design guidelines, but the application gets a special GUI. We already test that in a user testing.*

Herhe some Code from the mainActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // lädt die ActionBar
    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbarview);
```

and the main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also add  to the AndroidManifest.xml but it doesn´t have any effect.

also make a xml for the actionbar. Try a few things but dosen´t get the navigation to the bottom :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action Bar Tabs at the bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914035/action-bar-tabs-at-the-bottom)

Comment: I tried a split action bar (also edit the question) but it doesnt´t work, too. :(